# Single Click in Terminal to Select Text

Tags: macos, terminal, mouse

I've been searching for a while on this one and the only answers I can dig up are "use X11"...so I thought I would bring it to the experts.  Is there a way to configure mouse gestures/actions in the OS X Terminal app such that single-clicking on text copies the text to the clipboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do it with the built-in Terminal app, but this is a feature that some terminal replacement apps, like [iTerm 2](http://www.iterm2.com/), support.

[image]

Comment: Nice drop shadow ;)

Comment: It's standard OS X screenshot stuff. I know the screenshot doesn't really do anything, but the post looked a little short/bland.

Comment: The screenshot really sold me on this answer

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but not with an unmodified **left** click. If you want to remap the middle or right mouse buttons to copy text, you can do this with a combination of BetterTouchTool and Automator.

The automator part:

Create a service that accepts text as input.

Single action: **Do shell script.** The shell script is `/usr/bin/pbcopy`

[image]

Save the action. Use **System Preferences** to assign an obscure keyboard shortcut to the action.

Then, in **BetterTouchTool**, remap the center mouse button to the keystroke that triggers your action.

That's the short version. For an expanded version with screenshots and more detailed instructions, come back later tonight, but I'm at work now and only have a Windows PC.